# EXTJs visible rows

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, propertygrid

I have a Property Grid with some values. When i selected row, it becomes visible. Can i make all rows is visible right away? Thanks in advance.

Here's grid

```
var propGrid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
        url: 'fill-template-form-panel-id',
        id: 'propGrid',
        autoFill: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        width: '100%',
        disableSelection : true,
        source: {
        "name": "Vasya",
        "surname": "Pupkin"
},
        style: 'margin:0 auto;margin-top:10px;'
      });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it becomes visible" ? Isn't the row visible?

Comment: Rows is visible. Textfield, numberfield, etc becomes visible after clicking on row

Comment: Anybody can help me?! Please!!

Comment: Are you using some cell editing fields like text/combo inside grid row ? And on row click they are visible. Please expain what you want.

Comment: Yes, i do. I want, that they all are to be visible immediately when the table is opened. Is it possible?

Comment: Anybody can help me?